# How to pass output of lambda authorizer info to another lambda function in AWS API gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I have created two Lambda functions using C#. One is to authorize and another is to perform some business logic.

I have configured first Lambda function as API gateway Authorizer and second one as  Resource.

How I can pass the response of first lambda function to a API gateway request so that second one can read and continue with remaining processing?

Thanks
Satya

Answer (score 0):

If your first lambda function has been authorized by API Gateway then you can just call the second lambda function directly from the first one provided the first lambda has the correct permissions to call the second lambda.

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action: 
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: "*"
```

Comment: I don't have issues with permissions. The response context of authorizer is not passing to actual API resource as a request. I need to read some values from authorizer response and pass those values to request of actual API resource.